# Creating Xcode Scheme Progmatically

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to automate the creation and deployment of an iOS application through the use of scripts. The application requires several different schemes to support different variations of the app. I would like to automate the process of creating a new scheme (preferably in Python), but I cannot figure out how to do this other than in Xcode.

I would like to offer some methods which I have already tried, but research has not offered many leads. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Do you want to create the scheme file automatically? It is described at http://michele.io/the-project-file-part-2

Comment: Thanks @Mats for the basic information, but is there any material regarding getting current Xcode scheme details and creation

Comment: Analyze the difference at the project before and after the new sheme is created, do it for every Xcode version and update the script accordingly, also keep in mind that nothing prevents Xcode from updating internal files without notifying or asking you (apart from locking these files from editing of course).